# Manipulating scroll view in Corona SDK

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a class with a scroll view that has a width of 980. I also have about 100 buttons aligned 5 columns x 5 rows for each 320 width of my scroll view. The scroll works okay but I'm trying to achieve two things:

> 1. Allow scrolling only when slide length is about 50% of screen size
> 2. If the slide length is half the screen size, then it would immediately slide/scroll to the next 25 items. For example, in plain sight you would see buttons 1-25 then if you try to scroll, the next 25 objects would be displayed (buttons 26-50).

I followed the sample from [here](http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/widget/newScrollView.html) but I don't know how to implement what I want to do or if it's even possible to do this using scroll view. I hope someone can give me a good example or idea. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this: http://developer.coronalabs.com/code/slider-module-springboard-functionality-warning-shameless-promotion-inside. It works sort of like the iOS springboard.

Comment: I found a way using PagedScrollView but this might be a better approach so I'll give it a try. Thanks a lot.